# How to bind ListboxItem to textbox in wpf using vb

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

I'm trying put the item that is selected in the listbox to the textbox by using `Text="{Binding ElementName=list, Path=SelectedItem.Content}"` but the textbox just comes out blank

Here is the XAML:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="Mainwindowtext2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="78,132,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=list, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"/>
<ListBox x:Name="list" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="78,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"  >
        <ListBoxItem Content="1"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="2"></ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Really? Same code? when you choose the content of the listbox its shows in the textbox automatically?

Comment: I've created a new APF app, and pasted the code. It works.

Comment: Just remove the SelectedItem.Content and replace it with SelectedItem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code this work fine for me.

```
XAML
 <TextBox x:Name="Mainwindowtext2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="26" Margin="78,132,0,0" 
             Text="{Binding ElementName=list, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Width="133"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="list" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="59" Margin="78,74,0,0" SelectedIndex="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"  >
        <ListBoxItem Content="1"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="2"></ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: What exactly have you changed?

Comment: @Athari :I set SelectedIndex and Height to ListBox.

Comment: @Ravuthasamy Thanks! Now i know where I was wrong. The code was really correct. I was just using the listbox wrong. Thanks for noticing the height.